# Accessing json type data without knowing layout of data?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a file with JSON data I am loading using json.load.
Suppose I want to put a variable in the json data, which references another data field. How can I process this reference in python?

```
eg:

{
  "dictionary" : {
    "list_1" : [
      "item_1"
    ],

    "list_2" : [
      "$dictionary.list_1"
    ]
  }
}
```

when I come across $, I then want list_2 to grab the data from: dictionary.list_1
and extend list_2, as if I had written in my python code:

```
jsonData["dictionary"]["list_2"].extend(jsonData["dictionary"]["list_1"])
```

Comment: There is nothing standard; you'd have to write that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing in the JSON standard for doing references. My first suggestion would be to use [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) which does have references in the form of [Node Anchors](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586). Python has a good implementation of YAML which supports those.

That being said, if you're set on using JSON, you'll have to roll your own implementation.

One possible example(though this doesn't extend the current array by the referenced array because that's ambiguous in the case of dicts, it replaces the reference by the value it refers to) is below. Note that it doesn't handle malformed references you'll have to add the error-checking yourself or guarantee that there aren't malformed references. If you want to change it to extend instead of replacing, you can, but you know your use-case better than I so you'll be able to specify it that way. This is meant to give you a starting point.

```
def resolve_references(structure, sub_structure=None):
    if sub_structure is None:
        return resolve_references(structure, structure)
    if isinstance(sub_structure, list):
        tmp = []
        for item in sub_structure:
            tmp.append(resolve_references(structure, item))
        return tmp

    if isinstance(sub_structure, dict):
        tmp = {}
        for key,value in sub_structure.items():
            tmp[key] = resolve_references(structure, value)
        return tmp

    if isinstance(sub_structure, str) or isinstance(sub_structure, unicode):
        if sub_structure[0] != "$":
            return sub_structure

        keys = sub_structure[1:].split(".")
        def get_value(obj, key):
            if isinstance(obj, dict):
                return obj[key]
            if isinstance(obj, list):
                return obj[int(key)]
            return value

        value = get_value(structure, keys[0])
        for key in keys[1:]:
            value = get_value(value, key)
        return value
    return sub_structure
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_str = """
... {
...   "dictionary" : {
...     "list_1" : [
...       "item_1"
...     ],
... 
...     "list_2" : "$dictionary.list_1"
...   }
... }
... """
>>> obj = json.loads(json_str)
>>> resolve_references(obj)
{u'dictionary': {u'list_2': [u'item_1'], u'list_1': [u'item_1']}}
```